Expected value of a random variable X.
In a competition, there are  athletes participating, out of which  athletes are from the team "A." Define  as the minimum rank (or position) obtained by any "A" athlete. Find the expected value (mathematical expectation) of the random variable 
It is assumed that all athletes have an equal chance of finishing in any position, meaning each possible ranking arrangement is equally likely.
I am new to statistics, and I am completely at loss of how to start solving this task. Could you provide me with some hint or where to begin? Thank you

I would start by checking what you know about calculating the expected value of a random variable.

Here are a couple approaches you could try.

Approach 1: First, use the property that $$\mathbb{E}[X] = \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}P\{X \ge k\} = \sum_{k = 1}^{N-m+1}P\{X \ge k\},$$ where we used the fact that the minimum rank cannot be larger than $N-m+1$.
Next, try to figure out what is the probability that the minimum rank is at least $k$, i.e., what is the probability that all the team A athletes have a rank that is at least $k$? This will be the total number of ways to pick their ranks from $k,k+1,\ldots,N$ divided by the number of ways to pick their ranks. Finally, simplify the summation via the Hockey-stick identity.

Approach 2: Number the non-team A players $1,\ldots,N-m$. For each one, let $X_i = 1$ if the $i$-th non-team A player finished with a lower rank than any of the team A players, and $X_i = 0$ otherwise. Note that the minimum rank is then $$X = 1 + \sum_{i = 1}^{N-m}X_i.$$ Do you see why this is true? Now, figure out the probability that the $i$-th non-team A player finished with a lower rank than all $m$ team A players. Then, figure out the expected value of $X_i$. Finally, use linearity of expectation to figure out $\mathbb{E}[X]$.

The expected value of a random variable is the sum of the different possible values multiplied by their probability.
The possible values for $X$ are $1,2,...,N-m+1$, but we need to calculate their probabilities.
For $X=1$, any of the $m$ athletes can come first, so the probability is $\frac{m}{N}$.
For $X=2$, we need the first athlete to be one of the others $\left(\frac{N-m}{N}\right)$ and then the second athlete to be one of the $m$ $\left(\frac{m}{N-1}\right)$, so total probability $\frac{m(N-m)}{N(N-1)}$.
In general, for $X=n$, we need the first $n-1$ athletes to be the others $\left(\prod_{i=0}^{n-2}\frac{N-m-i}{N-i}\right)$ and then the $n$th athlete to be one of the $m$ $\left(\frac{m}{N-n+1}\right)$, so total probability $\frac{m}{N-n+1}\prod_{i=0}^{n-2}\frac{N-m-i}{N-i}$.
So the expected value is $$E[X]=\frac{m}{N} + \sum_{n=2}^{N-m+1}\left(\frac{nm}{N-n+1}\prod_{i=0}^{n-2}\frac{N-m-i}{N-i}\right)$$
You might be able to simplify this a little. I can see there would be a factor of $\frac{m}{N}$ in every term, but you would need to amend the product notation in order to isolate the $N$ denominator when $i=0$
